# Strange surface of my height map using displacement node

Tags: mesh, subdivision-surface, displacement, height-map, bump

I have problem with my height map. I plan to create a relief map using digital elevation model (DEM), which I will be able to print on A2 paper. I have DEM 10m (42 692 x 20 429 px) and in QGIS I clip this map to get my area of interest. Then I rescale map to get elevation range from 0 to 65 535 and save it as 16-bit unsigned TIFF.
So in blender **I used this .tiff file (4 860 x 3 690 px):**

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1k_Vowyp6-5OrtIx-G1bB4y-U3WiShJi5/view?usp=sharing

In Blender Im using Cycles render engine.

**Adaptive subdivision:**

[image]

**And for displacement:**

[image]

[image]

**Here's my render result (test with 200 samples, 4 860 x 3 690 px):**

[image]

**As you can see, the result have strange "terrace and grid":**

[image]
[image]

The result is worse when I use "displacement and bump" then when I use "displacement only". Also choosing another then sRGB color space make the result even worse. I tried to change texture interpolation and the best result I get with cubic but still there are visible "terraces".

It is possible to get rid of it or I have just bad quality height map (DEM)?
I'll be glad for any advice. **Thank you!**

**My blend file:**

[image]

Comment: Can you show us where on your map these artefacts occur?

Comment: Everywhere... I think it doesn't depends on for example height, they occur on whole map

Comment: I don't have the resources to render this efficiently, but my guess is these are compression artefacts. Your output format is png with 15%, does your png have the same issue? Can you render with no compression? If your final goal is to render the same straight down view, I suggest you use a bump map, as I don't think displacement is worth the trouble here.

Comment: In addition, make sure you set your output to 16 bit colors.

Comment: @eezacque thank you for your help

Comment: My problem is SOLVED. The problem was in my digital elevation model (DEM), because I saved it as 16-bit unsigned TIFF and that is no longer necessary. My DEM is 32-bit float so I just clipped my desired area in QGIS and then open in Blender. Then in texture node choose texture interpolation: cubic, color space: non-color. Now I have a nice clean texture without any artefacts even when I have displacement and bump at the same time.